# Booting too slow with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

When I first installed Windows 7, the booting was really fast. Then, I installed this and that, and now it's very slow in booting.

The turn-on to the welcome screen (the screen to input password) is pretty fast, but when I give the password, the screen turns black, and I have to wait quite a while.

- Is there any way to improve this?
- Is there any tool check what makes most of the booting time?

Comment: Are you using a solid color for your desktop wallpaper? There is a bug that makes start-up take 30 seconds or more to render a blank background. If this is the case, set a wallpaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of any additional program:

```
1.Push the windows logo button
2.type is search box msconfig
3.There are start up tab.You may take down progs you don't want
```

To measure time use http://www.soluto.com/ it also let you customize the start up process

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to see what programs run when you boot. Since you say it was fast until you started installing programs, that's the most likely cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this won’t let you know what’s making it boot slowly but it will improve it and make it faster...

First off try to reduce the amount of program that’s starting with windows. To do this in the start menu search-box type **msconfig** and hit enter. Then go to the Autorun-tab and uncheck unnecessary applications. Try to uncheck as much as you can but leave out anti-virus and firewall etc. Dont worry you can always restore an application to autostart by re-check it.

Second clean up your hard drive from unnecessary files. A simple way to do this is to type **cleanmgr** in the start menu, press enter, select your hard drive and wait. When it’s finished you will see a dialog with files to remove. Just check it all and hit OK, you won’t miss those files, honestly.

Third defrag. Start -> **dfrgui**. Run it on the hard drive that’s most fragmented. But this step can often be skipped in a win 7-machine.

Forth, update! Run windows update and try to update the drivers your system is using.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do is to optimize the ReadyBoot function of Windows 7, which uses the ReadyBoost feature to speed up the loading of all the code needed to load the OS. To do this, you need to install Microsoft's "[**Windows Performance Toolkit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx)" for your particular flavour of Windows 7 (X86 or X64), part of the Windows 7 SDK base development tools installation.

For further details see the link cited above as well as a Google search using keywords *xbootmgr readyboot* or a Google search using keywords *Windows On/Off Transitions Solutions Guide*

It helps to use the **Autologin** tool of **Sysinternals** to enable automatic login to your usual working account; the tool should be started from an elevated command line session in that user account, in a folder you've created for the purpose (it will store trace files there, which you can analyse later with other Performance Toolkit tools, if you are a Geek-with-no-Life (TM)), using the command line  *xbootmgr -trace boot -prepSystem -verboseReadyBoot*.

It will install an autostart entry and reboot the computer six times while optimizing boot time, and after a certain amount of activity at each boot, it will require UAC elevation, so you have to remain near the machine to answer the UAC dialogs. It then removes the autostart entry and reboots one final time.

On my Core 2 Duo T9400 notebook, the process took the better part of an hour, and the result was a 25% reduction in boot time--but others have noted up to a halving, it depends on how bad things are to start with on your machine.

The toolkit is also useful to see what software and drivers are slowing down hibernation, suspend, as well as the wakeup from those machine states--see the toolkit's Help file for for details.